# Populate UIPickerView data using http request

Tags: arrays, json, swift, http, uipickerview

I have this `UIPickerView` which will have data yet, but doesn't have data, since I make async http request

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        var dataCount = PickerData.count
        return dataCount
    }
```

happens before my data is loaded, how do I populate my `PickerData` after this function happens? I couldn't find any answers on any website, maybe I'm searching for wrong terms but still, i couldn't do it, i thought about making sync request, but I've read that it is a bad practice, so is there a good way to solve my problem?

Also I want to add, the data might change over time so I want to be able to change `PickerView` data too.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this question using `self.pickerview.reloadAllComponents()`

Answer (score 0):

`objective-c` code :
After loading the data from request you should call

```
[pickerview reloadAllComponents]
```

this will load the datasource of picker